# How to insert a list and insert a nested embed list in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this structure :

```
{
"_id": "blablabla",
"UUID": "50ED0565C5BF",
"Email": "foobar@bar.ca",
"FirstName": "Bacel",
"LastName": "ELbs",
"ClientID": "sa-sa",
"UserSettings": {
    "dateRangeMode": "1",
    "skillsMode": "1",
    "CalendarViewMode": "One Month"
},
"Filters": [{
    "Type": "Calendar",
    "Filter": [],
    "DefaultFilterID": ""
}, {
    "Type": "Calendar",
    "desc": "test",
     "Filter": [],
    "isDefault": false

}]
```

}

My objective is to **first** insert **one** new object to the *****Filters***** array **and** insert multiple items to the *Filters.Filter* embedded array :

so I'm trying the following approch :

```
static async saveFilter(UUID, Type, desc, isDefault, aFilters) {
     //let objectID  = UUID.replace(/-/g, "");
    return await user.update({
         UUID: UUID
       }, {
         $push: {
           Filters: {
             Type: Type,
             desc: desc,
             isDefault: isDefault
           },
           "Filters.Filter": ["a","b","c"]
         } 
        });
   }
```

I keep having this error :

> Cannot create field 'Filter:' in element {Filters: [ { Type:
> "Calendar", Filter: [], DefaultFilterID: "" }, { Type: "Calendar",
> desc: "test", isDefault: false } ]}

But I don't want to creat a new field, I simply want to add elements,

desired output is something like :

```
{
"_id": "blablabla",
"UUID": "50ED0565C5BF",
"Email": "foobar@bar.ca",
"FirstName": "Bacel",
"LastName": "ELbs",
"ClientID": "sa-sa",
"UserSettings": {
    "dateRangeMode": "1",
    "skillsMode": "1",
    "CalendarViewMode": "One Month"
},
"Filters": [{
    "Type": "Calendar",
    "Filter": [],
    "DefaultFilterID": ""
}, {
    "Type": "Calendar",
    "desc": "test",
     "Filter": [],
    "isDefault": false

},
{
    "Type": "Tower",
    "desc": "Tesla",
     "Filter": ["a","b","c"],
    "isDefault": false

}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
([playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1-XrR8pvtww))

```
db.users.update({
  UUID: UUID
},
{
  $push: {
    Filters: {
      Type: Type,
      desc: desc,
      isDefault: isDefault,
      "Filter": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I was looking for !!